# Difference between Trophy Truck and Hammer Truck?

Tags: truck

I just saw the video:

https://youtu.be/i85ya5wpTzA

In Baja 1000, of the many vehicles competing, there are two which interested me, mainly Trophy Truck and Hammer Truck ... What is the difference between the two? Other than the trophy truck having a faux fibre body and the Hammer truck having none. What's different underneath these trucks ??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two classes each of Trophy and Hammer Trucks:

- [Trophy Truck](http://score-international.com/raceinfo/score-rulebook/truck-classes/trophy-truck/)
- [Trophy Truck Spec](http://score-international.com/raceinfo/score-rulebook/truck-classes/trophy-truck-spec/)
- [Hammer Truck Unlimited](http://score-international.com/raceinfo/score-rulebook/truck-classes/hammer-truck-unlimited/)
- [Hammer Truck Limited](http://score-international.com/raceinfo/score-rulebook/truck-classes/hammer-truck-limited/)

The big difference between the Trophy and Hammer classes is the **Trophy is 2wd** and the **Hammer is 4wd** (must have a transfer case). The Hammer Trucks are built to be used in both desert racing as well as rock crawling. There are a lot of little differences between the two classes as well as a lot of little differences within the Trophy and Hammer sub-classes themselves. I believe the *Trophy Truck* and *Hammer Truck Unlimited* both are completely open as far as what kind of engine they can run, etc. The Spec/Limited class of each pare this down a little and give specifics in this area. Like I said, there's a lot of little differences between classes and sub-classes.

For extra information, you can also look at the [SCORE International Website](http://score-international.com/raceinfo/)

Comment: @JayakrishnanMenon - If you believe this answers your question, please click the checkmark to show the question is answered.